# Is it possible that someone can serve my website files by pointing to my ip address under his domain name?

Tags: security, ip

i have  website built in drupal. http://www.bhubaneswarlive.com hosted on linode.
Now somedays back i discovered that a Chinese website http://today.yangchenyun.com is serving my website too.

so i want to know whether he has copied my entire website files and database or he is just serving files and data by pointing to my linode's ip address (as said by linode support guy).
i.e Is it possible that someone can serve my website files by pointing to my ip address under his domain name?

When i update my website with new content both the domains show the new content.

Also one thing i have noticed that when i visit "restaurants link" on the right sidebar, which are just drupal taxonomy terms, perfectly shows list of data under its own url instead of redirecting to my website.I am asking this to know whether its related to drupal or my whole system has been copied.

can anyone suggest how to counter/solve this problem?

my server stack is

Linux- Debian
Nginx
Mariadb
php5-fpm
Drupal-7
fail2ban server

and some other softwares

on a Linode VPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both DNS use the same IP record. So yes, they simply recorded another domain name.

You have a very simple setting that you can use in Drupal, which is calle the `base_url`, this settings should alays be set in production servers.

Add this to you settings.php file:

```
$conf['base_url']="www.bhubaneswarlive.com"
```

You can also set it on the Drupal back Office interfaces, somewhere, but the right place is the settings file. If you have a multisite installation you can set that in the related settings files.

With this setting all pages links will contain reference to your website.

Then you can play with your Apache configuration and set a special named base virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName today.yangchenyun.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fush
</VirtualHost>
```

And then set any content you think appropriate for this domain name in `/var/www/fush`.

Comment: the base url thing didnt help, i had tried it already. That website still server my pages. One thing is that i had changed my website database tested with some new content, and the chinese website served from my database instantly with the new content.

Comment: Add the named-based virtualhost and see if it helps. They could have used a proxy but here it's more simple they simply have the same DNS address. So you need to handle this alternate `Hostname` on another Virtualhost. You could also add a default Virtualhost (catch all names) and one Virtualhost with the right name which would run the Drupal website. You are the owner of the server, so you can control the things done on the HTTP side depending on the hostname. You could also use mod_rewrite and work on the HTTP_HOST things.

Comment: thanks for the tip, the virtual host thing did it but is there a permanent way to discourage or disallow others to use my ip address to serve my files

Comment: You can plys with mod_rewrite, like in this example to [check the REFERER](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html) for static files, but name-based virtualhosts are the real solutions. You can also add headers to prevent iframes usage, and control IP for bad proxys.

Comment: my server has nginx running. so is there a link for that or any keywords to search for.